# PHP SQL loop outputs as 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, loops

I am trying to create a PHP loop to show the players the tournaments they are partaking in. I tried the function on phpMyAdmin, and I got the result that I wanted. But when I try to run this simple script on PHP, it outputs as 0 rows.

[image]

[image]

index.php

```php
chdir("../"); // path to MyBB
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require("./global.php");

if($mybb->user['uid']) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players, tourneys WHERE players.forumname = 1 AND players.tid = tourneys.id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // output data of each row
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each ro
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            $time = $row['time'];
            echo $name;
            echo $date;
            echo $time;
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 rows";
    }
}
```

Comment: `if($mybb->user['uid'])` that condition is stopping the query

Comment: You can also add a Try-Catch block to handle exception errors that may cause if the query returned 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in "if ($mybb->user['uid']) {" as suggested by @Dagon. Try to leave the well indented code to avoid this kind of confusion. Run the code below and post the the DB error output.

Try this:

```
<?php
chdir("../"); // path to MyBB
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require("./global.php");

if ($mybb->user['uid']) {

    $player_forumname = '1';

    // Return only the necessary fields
    $sql = "SELECT tourneys.name, tourneys.date, tourneys.time
            FROM tourneys
            INNER JOIN players ON players.tid = tourneys.id
            WHERE players.forumname = {$player_forumname}";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    // If the query fails display the error
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('MySQLi Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        die('0 rows');
    }

    // Returns only the associative array
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $time = $row['time'];

        echo 'Name:',$row['name'],'Date:',$row['date'],'Time:',$row['time'];
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors outputted, just says "0 rows". I was able to run the query through phpMyAdmin without any problems. I have a message that says "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Comment: DId you try Gustavo's suggestion (i.e. using `INNER JOIN`) ? And do you really wants this `where clause`? i.e.` WHERE players.forumname = 1` That `where` clause doesn't seem right